# ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RegisterSuccessModalComponent -> LoginComponent]:

Tags: angular

Need help please,
I want to call a function from LoginComponent in other component, here is my LoginComponent

```ts
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(){}
 doRegisterSession(){
    this.isRegisterLogin = true
  }
}
```

and this is my other component

```ts
import { LoginComponent } from '../../../login/login.component';
export class RegisterSuccessModalComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(
private _loginComponent: LoginComponent
){}
  skipModal() {
   clearInterval(this.interval);
   this._loginComponent.doRegisterSession();

   this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

and I got this error 
[image]

I created **LoginService** like this

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component'

@Injectable() 
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private _loginComponent: LoginComponent) {}

  doRegisterSessionService() {
    this._loginComponent.doRegisterSession();
  }
}
```

and changed import `LoginComponent` to `LoginService`, but it still error static injector like this..

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LoginService -> LoginComponent]:

Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: `LoginComponent` is a component here. It needs to be a service (`Injectable`) to be injected.

Comment: if you want to do that... check out https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction for component interaction.

Comment: Simple example on how to achieve communication between two components using `subject`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vts7zd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment - You have added a service but still you are getting this issue - The problem is you haven't injected your service in your module and you're trying to request the DI container to provide the `service` - Angular doesn't have that knowledge about it

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Use `providedIn` on your `injectable` decorator either the add `root` or use any of the module name you want to inject the service - Now you can try to inject the service on your `component`

Otherwise you can add `providers` directly on your `component` or `module`

**Adding Providers in component: (deprecated method)**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./style.css'],
  providers: [YourServiceClass] <--Add your service class
})   
export class RegisterSuccessModalComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private service: YouServiceClass){
      }
      skipModal() {
       clearInterval(this.interval);
       this.service.doRegisterSession();

       this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps - Happy coding :)

Comment: adding `providers` is deprecated now in components

Comment: That was the one part of the solution to fix this issue - he can use either the first option of using providers on module

Comment: That I know, Just saying this is deprecated now

Comment: i still cant solve my problem :(
already try all of your way, the frst is saying me Expected 0 - 1 argument, but got 2.
the 2nd way is still give me same error :'(

Comment: the frst is saying me Expected 0 - 1 argument - You got this error after adding `providedIn` can you please update your question with my change - because it's nothing to do with the issue